# PHP/JavaScript Debugging

Tags: javascript, php, debugging

Is there a PHP-enabled webserver, that is tailor-made for debugging?
I want to be able to step thru code, both php and javascript. There has to
be something that makes web development less painful,
but it does not seem to be mainstream, or maby my google-fu is failing me.
Any help appritiated.

Comment: I debug using echos since all debugging techs I saw have failed me. So they walked the plank. However, perhaps someone has a gem and he will share it with you! I shall keep an eye on here.

Comment: I haven't used it, but I've heard of XDebug.

Comment: XDebug can be good option with eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a windows machine, [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) should does the job. It has [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/index.php) which is really helpful. Regrading *JavaScript* [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Chrome Dev-Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) are great. Except the web-server itself or PHP extensions like XDebug, a powerful IDE can help you a lot as well.

Within your source-code, *Exception Handling* could be extremely useful -- `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` and `die` are the other useful options, but not as powerful as *Exceptions* when it comes to get rid of a bug. `console.log` comes really handy in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) is what we use at the company I work at. It provides full stack information that is really helpful when trying to determine where something went wrong in the codebase.

[Here's an example](http://blog.hamidnazari.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/xdebug-overwrites-var_dump-and-php-errors.png) of the error messages you'll get with it.